# How to replace the pattern w{3,3} with w{3}

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I meant any numbers in this regex expression.

```
w{1,1} --> w{1}
w{2,2} --> w{2}
```

and so on.

Comment: what would {1,2} return?

Comment: Won't change. I only want to replace w{<digit>,<same digit>} into w{digit}. All rest - without change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `w\{(\d*),\1\}` and replace it with `w{\1}`.

Here is a full example with python code:

```
import re
 re.sub(r'w\{\s*([0-9]+)\s*,\s*\1\s*\}', r'w{\1}', 'w{1,1}')
```

Explanation:

- we have to escape the curly braces: `\{` and `\}`
- we need one ore more number: `[0-9]+`
- this number is surrounded with zero or more whitespaces: `\s*`
- then the same numbers again, with a *backreference*: `\1`
- finally, we can use the backreference in the replacement too: `w{\1}`

Comment: import re

str = "somestring\w{3,3}somestring"
line = re.sub(r"w\{(\d*),\1\}", "w{\1}" , str)
print (line)

I'm missing something: "somestring\w{}somestring"